# Why int64(1.1*float64(time.Minute)) is an error while int64(0.5*float64(time.Minute)) is not in golang 1.9.2?

Tags: go

I meet a very strange bug in golang 1.9.2:
When I try to write `int64(1.1*float64(time.Minute))` shows an error. The compiler said that the constant truncated to integer.

But when I change 1.1 to other float like 1.2 0.5 1.7, it compiles!

And it can also compile when I write it like:

```
value:=1.1*float64(time.Minute)
fmt.Println(int64(value))
```

Is it some bug of go itself? I run go on ubuntu14.04 x64

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25584329/constant-1-truncated-to-integer

Comment: thx,I think I have solve my problem after reading that questions@abhink